# How to add dedication chapter to TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

How do I to add a chapter-name to this dedication and to add it to TOC, please?

```
\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   \slshape             % the text is in italics
   \raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{dedication}
ABC \\ DEF
\end{dedication}
```

I'm using report class.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post **complete** code. All questions should include a Minimal (non-)Working Example. Unless the problem is that it won't compile, the code should compile. This makes it easier for people to understand your question and easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\chapter*{Dedication}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newenvironment{dedication}
  {%\clearpage           % we want a new page             %%%<===== Comment this line
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }
\begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \tableofcontents 
 \chapter*{Dedication}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
  \begin{dedication}
    ABC 
    \par   %% or a blank line
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    DEF

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \usefont{T1}{LobsterTwo-LF}{bx}{it}
    John
  \end{dedication}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: for chapter*, I'm using this definition: `\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@
{\raggedleft \reset@font
\scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{30\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
{\raggedright \Huge #1}%
\par\nobreak
\par\nobreak
\vskip 45\p@
}} ` So, when I use your solution, I'm getting the chapter's title in one page and the dedication in another one.

Comment: @user3289501 So you do not want it formatted consistently with other chapters. Perhaps it should be a `section` or something instead? Normally dedications are not treated in this way so I'm not very clear what effect you are looking for.

Comment: @user3289501 You have to comment the first line in your dedication environment definition i.e., `%\clearpage`. I have marked it in the code. Did you do it?

Comment: @cfr, on which way might they be treated, please?

Comment: @HarishKumar, thank you for your answer, I'll take a look and provide you the result.

Comment: @user3289501 Well look at a book of any kind. The dedication is not usually a chapter which shows up in the table of contents. In some cases, it might have a title (e.g. in a thesis or dissertation). Usually, in most books, it isn't even formatted that way. Rather the wording itself makes its role clear e.g. 'This work is dedicated to...' or 'In memory of...' or 'With gratitude to...' or whatever. A book I just picked up just says 'To So-and-So\\For putting up with such-and-such for so many years...' *Acknowledgements* are sometimes listed but not the dedication.

Comment: @cfr, thank you so much, you've inspired me!